# Hover effects on class and id tied to each other?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a custom navbar on a site I'm making but I've run into an issue. I've searched around and have found some similar threads, but nothing that has worked for me. I have a navbar with an image and some text underneath. What I'm trying to accomplish is while hovering over either the text or image, the hover effect for both occurs. The issue is that for the image, the hover effect is done thru an ID and the text hover effect is done thru a class. Here is my markup for one of the sets.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-1">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")" title="HOME" style="margin-left:10px;">
        <div id="homenav"></div>
        <div class="navtext">HOME</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS for the image:

```
#homenav {
  margin: 0 auto; 
  display: block;
  width: 47px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('../Images/NAV_ICONS/NAV_HOME.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}

#homenav:hover {
  background: url('../Images/NAV_ICONS/NAV_HOME_RED.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

And the CSS for the text:

```
.navtext{
  font-family: RobotoCondensed-Bold, 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #00457c;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navtext:hover{
    color: #ee2e24;
}
```

And just for clarity, I'm simply trying to make both turn the same color red. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without javascript, you cannot do that. You could only put the navtext in red when hovering #homenav with this code:
 `#homenav:hover + .navtext {
     color: #ee2e24   
}`

Comment: Add common class between (lets say 'my-class') them and apply the css to that class: .my-class:hover { color: red };

Comment: check if this fidle can help you http://jsfiddle.net/f62ukmg4/ 

I have used `#homenav:hover + div.navtext 
{
    color: #ee2e24;
}`

Comment: Thanks, like @devsymediane said it only works one way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this fit your needs ?
Put both div (#navbar and .navtext) inside a wrapper div, then put your hover styles in those selectors:

```
#wrapper:hover #homenav
```

and

```
#wrapper:hover .navtex
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/40acz2v4/).

But the hover styles come for a hover over the whole wrapper div.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. So simple yet I just couldn't figure it out haha.

Answer (score 0):

When using css `:hover`, the property changes will only affect the element being hovered. You would have to use Javascript/JQuery to do this, but it's pretty straightforward.

First, we need to change the `:hover` css elements into classes like so

```
.navtextHover{
    color: #ee2e24 !important;
}
.homeNavHover {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/') no-repeat 0 0 !important;
}
```

We also need to add a new class. This class will essentially mean that they are all tied together when hovered - ie, when one is hovered, all will be treated as hovered. So add that to the HTML (I called it syncedHover)

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" title="HOME" style="margin-left:10px;">
        <div id="homenav" class="syncedHover"></div>
        <div class="navtext syncedHover">HOME</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Then the javascript merely adds the classes on hover and removes them on exit

```
$(".syncedHover").hover(
    function () {
        $("#homenav").addClass("homeNavHover");
        $(".navtext").addClass("navtextHover");
    },
    function () {
        $("#homenav").removeClass("homeNavHover");
        $(".navtext").removeClass("navtextHover");
    }
);
```

This could be written better by passing data to the JQuery method on hover so you don't have a list of `addClass` methods, but this isn't too cumbersome for only two elements.

This JSFiddle shows a working example with how it can be done https://jsfiddle.net/bou7mqk3/1/

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured. Any good resources you know of that could help me figure it out?

Comment: This does not need JS at all.

Comment: @ConnorLuddy your solution and my solution work differently. In order to get the functionality I have, you do need javascript.

Comment: Yep, this worked as well. I went with the simple wrapper solution above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put a class on the link instead. As in, the parent a tag that the two elements are nested inside.

In this HTML the only change is the additional class on the link - 'your-class', and I removed the unnecessary syncedHover classes:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" title="HOME" style="margin-left:10px;" class="your-class">
        <div id="homenav"></div>
        <div class="navtext">HOME</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

And then update your CSS to this:

```
.your-class:hover #homenav{
    background: url('../Images/NAV_ICONS/NAV_HOME_RED.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}

.your-class:hover .navtext{
    color: #ee2e24;
}
```

No JavaScript needed at all!

Comment: This is just a wrapper that whenever the wrapper is hovered over, the elements change, not when you hover over a element, the other one changes too. If this is in fact what OP wants, than this would be the easiest to implement, but I honestly don't know if it is.

Comment: Hey @JDrost1818 - Because they're both nested within the same element. When you hover over either of them you're also hovering over the parent element, which activates its :hover state and cascades the CSS down on to both elements.

Comment: the difference is that if you hit part of the wrapper that neither element is directly under, it will fire the hover as well.

Comment: That's true, but I would have assumed that if it was a nav bar with an image and text, they'd be in close proximity. This solution is definitely worth trying before introducing JavaScript.

Comment: Valid. Looks like it worked for OP which is all that matters